# Where are Waydroid-Android folders on Ubuntu?

Tags: android, wayland, 23.10, location, android-emulator

I have successfully installed [Waydroid](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/run-android-apps-games-linux/) and the 1DM Android browser, and I have downloaded a file with this browser. It had asked me to set where to download, and in Android under Waydroid it is this: `/storage/emulated/0/Movies/`.

I have read [online](https://forums.ubports.com/post/58185) that this corresponds to `~/.local/share/waydroid/data/media/0/Movies`. But I couldn't enter `~/.local/share/waydroid/data/media/0/Movies`, until I have changed ownership rights (`sudo chmod -R a+rwx`). But then I see no `Movies` folder and the rest, but different folders with no interesting files:

[image]

That was why [these](https://docs.waydro.id/faq/setting-up-a-shared-folder) instructions (on how to create a shared folder by mounting that location) fail with  `mount point does not exist`.

Within Waydroid I can use a file manager to move files around, but not outside Waydroid, which itself is not accessible from Ubuntu.

[image]

Maybe the path `~/.local/share/waydroid/data/media/0/` is wrong?